Is the set $A = \{ (x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2} : x \geq 1, 0 \leq y \leq 1/x \} $ compact?
Discuss the compactness of the set $A = \{ (x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2} : x \geq 1, 0 \leq y \leq 1/x \} $  endowed with the euclidean topology.
Intuitively what I see is that $A$ consists of the points below the graph of the map $x \mapsto 1/x$ in the first quadrant where the $x$ coordinate is greater than or equal to $1$. So $A$ is not bounded and it can´t be compact. To show it´s not compact, for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ define
$$
 U_{n} = (0, n) \times (-\frac{1}{n} , \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{2}) \cap A
$$
Then $U_{n}$ is an open set relative to $A$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $A = \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} U_{n}$. Suppose there exists some $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $U_{n_{1}}, \ldots, U_{n_{k}}$ cover $A$. Let $m = \operatorname{max} \{n_{1}, \ldots, n_{k} \}$ and note that $ A = \bigcup_{i = 1}^{k} U_{n_{i}} = A \cap (0, m) \times (-\frac{1}{m}, \frac{1}{m} + \frac{1}{2})$. But then we can take  $(m+1, \frac{1}{m+1}) \in A$ and it does not belong to this cover. So $A$ fails to be compact. Does this cover work? Also, I know that $A$ is not bounded by raw intuition, but right now I don´t see how to construct a formal proof

You could choose the simpler definition for $U_n = ((0,n)\times \Bbb R)\cap A$

If a set $A$ is unbounded, we can show it is not compact by taking the following open cover: $$U_n = B(\mathbf{0}, n).$$
This is an open cover for $\mathbb{R}^2$ and so is an open cover for $A$. (If you wish to be rigorous, we can consider $V_n = U_n \cap A$ - by definition of the subspace topology these are open in $A$). Yet any finite subcover has a maximum $N$, and so cannot contain $(N, \frac 1N)$ which has distance $\sqrt{N^2 + N^{-2}} > N$ from 0. (The details may differ if your metric is not $d_2$ but the idea is the same).
